# What's the meaning of "grapevine"?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, word-meaning

In the book I'm reading there's this sentence:

> The mother stood on the sidelines [of a soccer field] and watched her lanky son **grapevine** across the field with the other boys

I don't understand the meaning of grapevine here. It seems to be a verb... The boy is playing soccer or entering the field.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The **[grapevine](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grapevine_(dance_move))** is a dance step where you step sideways with your feet crossing alternately in front and behind each other. Used as a verb, it would mean to use a grapevine step, either while dancing or, as in your example, as an athletic warmup.

I found [a video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3lBOQ5A1QrQ) of someone demonstrating the grapevine as an athletic warmup.